Does any physical entity last forever?
First of all, if this question is not appropriate for this stack exchange, feel free to move it to some other stack exchange, like physics. Anyway, my question is this. We have all heard that "nothing lasts forever". But is that true? Are there some things that do last forever? I am a mathematical platonist, so I believe that mathematical objects exist eternally and timelessly. So, I should narrow down the question to whether any physical object lasts forever. Does any physical entity last forever? Also, what have philosophers, especially philosophers of physics, written about this question?

We also heard that nothing comes from nothing, everything changes and all crows are black. Those are not meant literally either. There are vague restrictions like "normal conditions", almost never spelled out. On top of that, "thing", "last" and "forever" are too vague to expect a straight yes/no. Is universe as a whole a "thing"? How much of alteration can "lasting" take? Does any infinite stretch of time count as "forever"? Because one can arrange that with time dilation near black holes. There is nothing we know of preventing a non-interacting photon from "lasting forever".

Nothing is the only thing that lasts forever. Nothing will be there long after the universe is gone.

@user4894 Only a diamond is forever.  Sorry moderators, I cannot resist; will delete this transitory comment in a day.

For a materialist, mathematical objects do not have an "existence" (in the sense that they interact with materially existing things) beyond being little vortices in our brain patterns. As such, they will cease to exist with the brains containing them which, on the individual level, is rather soon. On the collective level though the life time may be longer, as long as the species'; after all, these little vortices tend to get duplicated through journals and conferences. That's a bit like distributed cloud storage: You can delete a few nodes without losing data (but you do need  the cloud).

@GratefulDisciple Please do not delete it -- it's the proper answer!

If the passing time destroys all things in the end, the only things that can exist forever are those outside of time. – „Before you have formed the earth, from everlasting to everlasting you are God.” (Psalms 90,2)

We don't know yet.

@GratefulDisciple A diamond is only forever as long as you don't shatter it or set it on fire.

@user4894:  Everything will be there, too, in theory.  It is infinite.

The body of the question clarifies it so this cannot be an answer, but... if we assume that a big bang (or a god, depending on what one believes in) can create a universe from nothing - then even nothing does not last forever! At some point, a big bang or bored god might (and on sufficiently big scales, probably has to?) come along and turn the nothing into something...

@JimmyJames Didn't know that diamond cannot survive being set on fire.  But in the first place, I was jesting.  Maybe gemstone companies capitalizing on selling tokens of "eternal love" (which cannot be an answer since the Q asks for a "physical entity") can upstage De Beers of their claim that their product "is forever", since a gemstone did survive the fire test.

@GratefulDisciple I got that you were joking but I wasn't sure the response about it being the right answer was a joke.  Diamonds are created from coal, so it makes sense that they burn. They can also shatter when dropped if they land just right (wrong.) I only point it out because it's kind of cool to watch them burn and there seems to be a general misconception that diamond is the most durable substance. It is very hard but also brittle. Sorry Minecraft fans, but diamond is not useful for making swords or armor.

Please replace "forever" with "eternity". Eternity is the appropriate philosophical term and is discussed by a number of philosophers. "Forever" is a colloquial term for infinite time. Eternity includes the possibility of existence outside of time.

@JimmyJames I think Peter is playing along with my joke as well, so he is not serious in its being the "right answer".  After all, De Beers's advertising agency is not saying it as a  philosopher of physics!  But yes, thanks for correcting the misconception.

Protons might
The most widely accepted model of nuclear particles says they last forever. If they do decay, experimental results put a lower limit on their half-life at 10 to the power of 34 years; for comparison, the Universe is only about 10 to the power of 10 years old.

I thought they eventually will end up in black holes?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica nope - there’s a lot of space between black holes.

Yes, of course. Empty space ;-).

Will they'd survive the heat death of the universe? I suspect they might, but I don't know.

@terdon Why not? Heat death just posits that everything will become static, but all the constituents are still there.

@DaleM I think that would depend on how the expected lifespan of supermassive black holes (~10^100 years) compares to the expected time before an arbitrary proton would end up being gravitationally drawn into one. On these sorts of timescales gravity can still be a significant factor even over extragalactic distances, and I'm not actually sure what even the order of magnitude of the latter would be.

@Idran the expansion of the Universe is faster than the speed of light so any protons that are not now within ‘range’ of a black hole will never encounter them. Those in deep intergalactic space for example.

Blackholes will cease to exist due to hawking radiation. The idea of the universe as we know it still may exist. But if we take everything out of "space" then we could still argue that space is there. Whether you consider space something or the absence of things is the main factor in that thought. We could consider dark matter, but that is hypothetical anyway, It is a fun thought but still just a hypothesis.

Wat no electron?

Protons can (and will,  uh, probably) decay gravitationally, that is to say,  all of their energy can end up in such a small place that they'll form a black hole.   The time scale is incredibly long,  something like 10^10^1000 times the age of the universe,  but,  pretty soon compared to forever

I think that if you believe that the universe comes to an end then in a sense nothing does "last forever - nothing important in the eye of an emotional human at least. We are but a fraction of time in the universe and once we are gone the question you are asking won't even matter anymore. If quantifiable math exists in the end it still won't matter because there won't be anyone to use it. Some may argue that time lasts forever, but time is only a condition of subjective experience, we came up with the idea of time to begin with. So with that logic, if we aren't here to experience the passing of time then it could said that it also does not last forever.

+1 Welcome! Heat death of the universe certainly would be an end to all things physical. : D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe?wprov=sfla1

@JD it would be the end of all interesting things, but not the end of all things. A homogenous soup of particles is still a thing.

@Chieron I thought physics had reduced particles to immaterial fields? But I admit that a "soup of particles" is more intuitive, certainly.

@JD even a field that is the same everywhere is still a physical thing. The heat death just means that there is no available energy anymore for anything interesting to happen (only some minor fluctuations). In a way, this is also the end of time, as there are no events to mark its passing.

@Chieron A field that's non-differentiable, non-observable, non-sensible, non-conceivable, can't do work, and not to subject time is a physical thing? Lo, and empiricism has fallen mightily. Apparently we have different notions of what physical means. ; ) I'm playing.

Presumably mathematics begins with 'one', but with a continuous expansion of the universe at some time at any locality not one thing will be observable and then what use will mathematics have?

Photons (not protons) might be your best bet. There is a lot of empty space in the universe. Most of the photons emitted by the Sun would miss hitting anything, so I don't see why they shouldn't go on forever. Neutrinos probably have a long life ahead of them.
Of course, neither of them can expect a very interesting life; just a long and uneventful one.
(A photon moves at the speed of light, so, according the special relativity, time does not pass at all in the photon's frame of reference. If photons could think, they would not think they were living forever.)

I humbly think this is the best of the physics answers. The only thing I'd qualify is that cosmological expansion would tend to stretch out the wavelength of the photon such that its energy approaches zero as time goes to infinity. But I don't think there's any known reason for them to entirely cease.

@jecado  "Why am I so tired", said the photon, "I seem to be running out of energy".

As others have answered, if the universe were to come to an end, it would be hard to claim that any physical objects survived. It was also pointed out that time itself is subjective and would therefore cease to exist without anyone to observe it. However, I would argue that it is merely our understanding of time that is subjective, while time itself is an instance of change. Either way you look at it, either there must be change or eternity for any given object. So far, unless I am mistaken, we have not discovered anything that does not decompose at all.
In other words, whether an object continues to exist or not is the debate of the ship of Theseus, i.e. it is merely a question of whether the observer considers it to be the same object as it changes. We know that while energy and matter changes, they do not cease to exist. If our solar system was swallowed by a black hole, you could argue that it is still in there. You could also argue that the coin in your pocket is no longer the same after it was scratched by your keys. In this sense, only our ideas can really be said to exist beyond the lifetime of matter, and since our ideas can not exist without us, nothing can last forever.

Welcome! It's a decent response. Generally, we try to appeal to citations to establish the factual nature of the response (as opposed to our personal opinions). If you decide to stick around, please read: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Self-evidently something must last as long as time itself exists, which presumably qualifies as "forever".

If we assume that the lifetime of the universe is not finite (like ending in a big crunch or big rip), physicists are almost certain that the energy/mass within it will not go away. We call it the principle of conservation of energy. Together with the conservation of momentum and charges, it is one of the fundamental princriples of physics that we have come to rely on.
However: Physics is an observational science. And while we have no reason to believe that energy conservation could/should be violated, the outcome of a single experiment could still prove us wrong. As has happened before with the symetries (and we can be glad that those symetries are broken because half the universe would be antimatter otherwise).
In the end, we cannot know because we cannot observe it.

We do not know. We cannot know.
Physics is an iteration of detecting more and more unexplainable borderline cases, followed by theory improvement, followed by another round of looking for even rarer, more-border borderline cases.
Decay is one of these things.
We are pretty sure we know everything that's to know about decay for timespans up to, say, 10^10 years.
But nobody knows whether therer some additional, not-yet-known interaction that can cause decays on the 10^11 year scale.
And there's no end to this!
Even if we could improve our theories that we'd be reasonable confident that something stays stable for 10^20 years, we might have been overlooking an effect that becomes relevant only after 10^30 years have passed!
And after that, there might be something that's relevant only after 10^40 years.
And since we can never be sure that there isn't some new physics in the very long term, we cannot know.
The best we can do is make informed speculation, but we cannot know.
Eternity is just too long to determine anything about it using physics.
Or with any other branch of science, actually. Our experiences are limited to our timespans after all, and while we can extrapolate a lot beyond that by looking at faraway stars, or at ensembles of 10^10 atoms, there's only so far we can look and so many atoms we can put into a probe; a brilliant trick will allow us to push the limit of our knowledge by orders of magnitude, but orders of magnitude are far too minuscule compared to infinity.
Now there are potential scenarios where this argument will fall down.
For example, we could find out that the universe will eventually collapse again. It's not a likely scenario, our current knowledge says it will not, but in theory, we could be wrong.
In that scenario, everything would be finite because the Big Crunch will return everything to the primordial particle soup and nothing will stay unchanged.
For another example, we might be able to find a workable Theory of Everything that simply disallows all the processes that might cause decay for specific particles (photons were mentioned).
We couldn't be 100% sure that the theory is really comprehensive, but if a theory covers everything and we do not see anything that violates that theory, we could sort-of confident that we have the ultimate theory and that it will continue to hold until everything is photons. Still not fully confident: The killer argument is still that there might be unexplained interactions that we just cannot measure and make theories for because they happen only every, oh, 20^50 years or so.

Like @Conifold I consider your question rather general and also some of its terms a bit cloudy. Long time and short time are relative concepts, and "forever = eternity" is often used in colloquial or religious language, but not as a precise quantity of time.

Therefore I propose to focus on the concept of the Characteristic Life Span (= CLS) of different things in our universe:
Human beings have a CLS of some decades, animals like mayflies have
CLS of some days or weeks, while a tortoise has a CLS of 100 years.
The proton has a CLS of at least 5.9 × 10^33 years, while certain
resonances from elementary particles have a CLS less than 10^-15 secs.
Stars like the sun have a CLS of 5 billion years. The universe
exists at least since 13 billion years, we do not know neither its origin nor its end.

I agree with you that for some things, e.g.,  mathematical
propositions, it is not meaningful to apply the concept of time at
all.



True. Due to the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

It is important to remark that the Laws of Thermodynamics apply ONLY to thermodynamic systems.
You ask about "nothing" (..."that nothing lasts forever?"); if any thing can be considered a thermodynamic system, the Laws of Thermodynamics apply to it. In this case, a thing is a physical object (an object perceived by means of experience).
So, the Laws of Thermodynamics condition the definition of a physical object, and apply to it. The following list introduce the Laws of Thermodynamics ordered by dependencies:

1st law: Energy conserves: while all physical objects permanently exchange energy with the environment, the first law requires the object to be considered as isolated from the environment. Entropy loses its meaning on a physical object which changes its energy content.
3rd law: entropy is zero at 0[Kelvin]. Entropy cannot be directly measured, so, there is this convention that says that it is zero at zero degrees Kelvin. This is just a convention that enables the second law. Without this, measuring entropy is not possible.
0th law: Temperature is a transitive relationship. This also enables the second law. Without this, measuring entropy is not possible.
2nd law: If

a) the first law is fulfilled;
b) there is a referential value for absolute entropy (0K, Third Law), and
c) temperature becomes a physical quantity instead of a subjective feeling (Zeroth Law),
THEN: entropy can be assessed. The laws says that entropy is zero or positive along time. Entropy means "energy dispersal"; energy dispersal means that all molecules or particles in a billiard ball dissipate into the next level of disorganization. In general, that means that any object loses its internal order (not always, but often). So, a system made internally of hot water, and externally, by a spherical surface of solid ice, tends to melt into an homogeneous fluid which loses any shape. Apples rotten with time. Plastic decomposes with time. Metal corrodes, etc.





In synthesis, all physical objects dissipate with time (in your words, "nothing lasts forever"); that is what physical laws state. The Second Law of Thermodynamics is the corollary of Thermodynamics.

The laws of thermodynamics arise from statistical mechanics: they describe the behaviours of large numbers of particles, not the individual particles. The 2nd law of thermodynamics has nothing to say about a single photon, electron, or quark. A photon does not "dissipate with time"; it just keeps on going unless it is absorbed--and, given the emptiness of most of the universe, that is unlikely for any individual photon.

@SimonCrase The problem here is the classical definition of "system" (a set of interrelated parts). If a photon has parts, it cannot be deemed eternal. The second law of thermodynamics does not specifically address photons, right, NOR does it physical gases. Classical thermodynamics applies just to ideal, not real gases. A physical gas tends to adhere to these laws, given certain subjective concessions (e.g., mass-energy equivalence does not apply, try the mental experiment). Similarly, a proton would follow these laws, with the differences being a matter of these subjective concessions.

"If a photon has parts, ..." Now that is a novel idea. How would you propose to test it?

@SimonCrase physically, out of your head, there's just energy, not apples or photons. Energy evolves, never dissappears. Things like rainbows, apples or photons are metaphysical creations, dependent on our subjectivities (if you are blind, rainbows don't exist for you). So, the fact of apples or photons having parts is a metaphysical idea (like this thread). This is not about physics (in addition, only physical facts are scientifically measurable). There's nothing to test. The notion of systems having parts allows experience, and not the opposite.

Does it matter? Pun intended.
If the universe is not supposed to last, why would any matter last?
If the universe is supposed to collapse at one moment, everything would have the same fate, hence nothing physical effectively lasts.
